# C++ Executable cannot find library at runtime, even though it's in /usr/lib (On Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, panda3d

I'm creating a game in c++ with the Panda3D framework on Ubuntu. All of the Panda3D shared libraries are in `/usr/lib/panda3d` and all of the headers are in `/usr/include/panda3d`. I'm compiling with SCons, but I've tried it with gcc and it's the same, so here are the commands:

`g++ -o src/main.o -c -fPIC -O2 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/panda3d -Iinclude src/main.cpp`

`g++ -o Test src/main.o -L/usr/lib/panda3d -lp3framework -lpanda -lpandafx -lpandaexpress -lpandabullet -lp3dtoolconfig -lp3dtool -lp3direct -lpthread`

And here is the error I get when I run the executable:

`./Test: error while loading shared libraries: libp3framework.so.1.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

There isn't much in the code, just initializing a Panda3D window, so I doubt that's the culprit.

As I said before, the libraries are in `/usr/lib/panda3d`, I've checked about a million times now and it's driving me crazy. I can't think of a single reason why I would get this error. Any help is appreciated :)

Edit:

I was looking through my files and there's a `panda3d.conf` file  in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` with one line: `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/panda3d`. Does this have anything to do with it?

Edit #2:

I used the path in the above edit as the library path and got the same results, unfortunately.

Comment: You have to run `ldconfig` after adjusting the library search paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't think of a single reason why I would get this error.

The reason is very simple: the dynamic loader hasn't been told to look in `/usr/lib/panda3d` for shared libraries, and so doesn't.

You can run your program with:

```
LD_DEBUG=files,libs ./Test
```

and observe which directories the loader is searching.

> `panda3d.conf` ... with one line: `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/panda3d`

That is the wrong directory (or at least not the one where your libraries are).

One way to fix this is to correct the above path to `/usr/lib/panda3d` and run `sudo ldconfig`.

Another way is to add `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/lib/panda3d` to your link line.

Comment: thx so much, it worked! I've only dealt with static libraries so far, so I didn't know you had to do let the linker know where the library is at runtime.